# Image for sharing on Facebook/G+?

Tags: html, facebook, images, meta-tags

Is it possible to add an image to a html page that only shows up when sharing page on Facebook/G+? The image should not be visible in the html page since it contains a Flash game, but I would like it to show up when you post a link to the url on social sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can. Just add 
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/shareimage.jpg"/>`
at the top of the html page that you want to share. The image path that you use here will come up in the facebook. 
Refer [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm on Google Plus, but not on Facebook. The title appears, but not the description or the image.

Comment: Just found this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: For the description and title you need to add : "og:description" and "og:title" meta tags similar to "og:image". Please refer the link in my answer.